# git command to show the merge sources for %A and %B

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-merge-conflict

What I want to know are the commits from which %A and %B are drawn.

I am writing a merge driver that can apply domain knowledge and clean up 99% of merge conflicts in a certain set of files for which the default merge driver cannot. But conflicts can still happen and should be labelled appropriately.

Any reasonable display form is possible. I can parse output with regex if need be.

Comment: Git smuggles this information in environment variables, but this (a) is not documented and (b) is subject to change. You can try using those env vars but if it breaks when you upgrade Git, remember, I warned you. :-) (Dump out the entire environment; it should be reasonably obvious what to use here, if they haven't changed it already.)